How to implement flutter local schedule notification?
I am trying to implement flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.4 in my flutter app for getting daily notification from my app, even app is terminated. It was working perfectly when I installed apk file in my real device. But when I download the app from Google play store, now it's not working. I am not getting any more notification from app.
I am using package:
flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.4
My main.dart file code:
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  /// for notification ///

  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
  AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
  );

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);


  /// for appwrite ///

  Client client = Client();
  client
      .setEndpoint(AppWriteConstant.endPoint)
      .setProject(AppWriteConstant.projectId)
      .setSelfSigned(status: true);

  runApp(MyApp(client: client));
}

Here is the code for dailynotification function:
static void sendDailyNotification(String balance) async {
    if (await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
            .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
                AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
            ?.requestNotificationsPermission() ??
        false) {
      AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
          AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.high,
              playSound: true);

      NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
          NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
          0,
          'Test Notification',
          'Daily test notification',
          RepeatInterval.daily,
          notificationDetails);
    }
  }

Here you go with my AndroidMenifest.xml file code::
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <application
        android:label="MoneyGer"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />


        <!-- tag for flutter local notification -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" android:exported="true"/>
        <service android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.NotificationService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:exported="true"/>


    </application>
</manifest>

I call the function in homescreen initState function:
 @override
  void initState() {
    final monthlyBudgetState =
    Provider.of<MonthlyBudgetProvider>(context, listen: false);

    NotificationServices.sendDailyNotification('3000');
    super.initState();
  }

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue? Notification should work, even the app is terminated. Please go through all given code and lemme know the issue and how to solve? Thanks in advance!

What is the OS version of the device you tested? Have you tried testing on more than one device?

I tried in android (Redmi Note 10s) and I will try in another device and let you know the outcome. @tomerpacific
